# Super class object invoking a subclass constructor? How does that work?

Tags: java, static, polymorphism

```
public class NewClass 
{ 
    public static class superclass 
    { 
        static void print() 
        { 
            System.out.println("print in superclass."); 
        } 
    } 
    public static class subclass extends superclass 
    { 
        static void print() 
        { 
            System.out.println("print in subclass."); 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        superclass A = new superclass(); 
        superclass B = new subclass(); //This line?
        A.print(); 
        B.print(); 
    } 
}
```

I came across this code while learning [static binding from geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-vs-dynamic-binding-in-java/). I am unable to understand this particular line:

> superclass B = new subclass();

Not sure how this works. Basically, are we creating an object of super class and invoking the subclass' constructor? That doesn't make much sense to me because I have always seen and am used to : `A obj = new obj();` type object creation.

Comment: Beside the peculiar naming standards, there are **`static`** contexts right where the question is about instances and polymorphism. That got complicated very quickly

Comment: *"are we creating an object of super class and invoking the subclass' constructor?"* No, `new subclass()` is creating an object of the subclass, and assigning it to a variable of type `superclass`, which means that you can only use that variable to call methods declared on the superclass.

Answer (score 3):

While preparing my answer, I found that I had to use the words superclass and subclass in two different meanings. I'll rename the classes to be `Thing` and `Car` and use the words "superclass" and "subclass" for the general concepts.

```
public class NewClass 
{ 
    public static class Thing
    { 
        static void print() 
        { 
            System.out.println("print in superclass."); 
        } 
    } 
    public static class Car extends Thing
    { 
        static void print() 
        { 
            System.out.println("print in subclass."); 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Thing A = new Thing(); 
        Thing B = new Car(); //This line?
        A.print(); 
        B.print(); 
    } 
}
```

An expression `new Car()` always creates an instance of type `Car`. Always. And the result is [a reference to] an instance of `Car`.

Now, you can store [a reference to] an instance of `Car` into a variable of any type that allows for `Car` instances. And that is:

- a `Car`-typed variable,
- a variable declared with any superclass of `Car` (and this matches a `Thing B` declaration),
- a variable declared with an interface type directly or indirectly implemented by `Car`.

So, what happens with the line of code

```
    Thing B = new Car(); //This line?
```

It creates a new `Car` instance, and therefore of course invokes the `Car` constructor (*1) (*2). And then it stores a reference to this instance in the variable `B`, which allows for all kinds of `Thing` instances as long as they inherit from `Thing` and thus support everything that is expected from a `Thing` object.

And what happens at

```
    B.print();
```

It calls the `print()` method of the instance that's referenced by `B`. And as that instance is a `Car` instance, you get the `Car.print()` results, not the `Thing.print()`.

Some more remarks:

If `Car` had some additional methods not found in `Thing` (e.g. a `drive()` method), the compiler wouldn't allow you to call them on `B`, as not all `Thing` objects have them, but only some specialized `Thing` versions (i.e. the `Car` ones).

And I recommend to get used to the Java naming conventions, e.g. that classnames always begin with an upper-case letter and variables with lower-case. Java guys are so much used to these conventions that we find it really confusing to read code that doesn't follow these rules.

(*1) In your case the constructor is not explicitly defined, but auto-generated by the Java compiler.

(*2) A subclass constructor always calls the constructor of its superclass, and so on up to the `Object` constructor, to initialize all the aspects of the instance that the subclass inherits from its superclass.